# How to add fixed header and scrollview table rows in relativelayout?

Tags: android, xml

My intention is to make the header fixed with scroll able rows, so that the header can be stable for the user to add values inside the table. How to add scrollview inside table row after the table heading, here is my code,

activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_margin="40dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Department"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="B.E/B.Tech"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="M.E/M.Tech"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add a rough diagram of what you need .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to put the header/title out of the `TableLayout` and then need to wrap `TableLayout` inside `ScrollView`

I did a little modification in your code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.TableActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:text="Department"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="40dp">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="B.E/B.Tech"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="M.E/M.Tech"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyway, I think you should consider using `RecyclerView` instead if expecting to show list of data. As `RecyclerView` is recommended way to handle list of data

Comment: The scroll view must be happen after the tablerow 1. i.e., fixed header[tablerow1] and scrollable footer[remaining tablerow]

Comment: The current answer should do as your expectation